# 500 - Internal server error - on Javascript Function asp call

Tags: javascript, html, iis, asp-classic, webforms

I have this *javascript* function on an html webform. I am getting a very generic error 500 back from the chrome debugger. "There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

After some research it appears that is is usually an issue with an IIS config instead of a code issue. I wanted to confirm this before I go changing things in IIS. I know close to nothing about IIS. The IIS version is 6.2. Does this appear to be a code issue or is this something that I will need to correct in IIS?

Here is my js script:

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(chosen)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","recruiter_Info.asp?q="+chosen,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}    
</script>
```

Here is my ASP

```
<%
response.expires=-1

sql="select tName, tDisplayName from [tlmain].[dbo].[tblSkillSet] join tlmain.dbo.tblenum on [tlmain].[dbo].[tblSkillSet].nSkillID = tlmain.dbo.tblEnum.nIndex join tlmain.dbo.tblUser on [tlmain].[dbo].[tblSkillSet].nUserID = tlmain.dbo.tblUser.aUserID where nconstraintid = 110 and tName not like '%old%' and tlmain.dbo.tblUser.bDeleted <> '1' and tDisplayName like "
sql=sql & "'%" & request.querystring("q") & " Recruiter%' ORDER BY tName"

set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA SOURCE=mysour;UID=webform;PWD=mypass;DATABASE=mydb; "
set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.Open sql,conn

Response.Write "<label for=""recruiter""><span>Choose Recruiter</span>   </label>" & vbcrlf
Response.Write "<select name=""recruiter"" size=""10"">" & vbcrlf
while not rs.EOF
    Response.Write "<option value=""" + rs.Fields ("tName") + """>" & rs.Fields     ("tName") & "</option>" & vbcrlf
    rs.movenext
wend
Response.Write "</select>"
%>
```

Comment: You should look at the server error message.  500 means internal server error. It could be the code you need to look at the stacktrace on the server to get a better understanding of what is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you @broso05. That was what I needed to look at. It turned out to be a sql permissions issue.